# IIS Express references machine.config versus project web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am writing a WsCF service to retrieve data for multiple clients. I have a service layer that references business manager objects. In essence on the service call, I want to retrieve the provider type (a custom enum in my code) and the connection string from the web.config.

For some reason, the code is unable to find the settings in my project web.config.  I am gathering the IIS Express AND the VS development web server are referencing the machine.config.  How do I override this.  It is extremely frustrating.  As you can see from the snippet the setting AND the connection string name exist, but the code never picks it up.

My code:

```
Private Sub GetDBInformation()
    Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration
    config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Nothing)
    If (config.AppSettings.Settings.Count > 0) Then
        Dim Setting As System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement
        Setting = config.AppSettings.Settings("DB TYPE")
        If Not (Setting.Value = Nothing) Then
            Select Case Setting.Value
                Case "SQL SERVER"
                    provider = ProviderType.SqlServer
                Case Else
                    provider = ProviderType.OleDb
            End Select
        End If
    End If

    If (config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0) Then
        connection = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings("UMADB").ConnectionString
    End If
End Sub
```

The web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="UMADB" 
         connectionString="Data Source=***********;Initial Catalog=UMA;UserID=********;Password=***********"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<appSettings>
    <add key="DB TYPE" value="SQL SERVER" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a really roundabout way of accessing the configuration settings. I don't know why or how you got to the `machine.config`, but there's an easier way.

Don't forget to import the `System.Configuration` namespace.

```
Dim Setting As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("DB_TYPE")
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DatabaseSetting) Then
    Select Case Setting 
        Case "SQL SERVER"
            provider = ProviderType.SqlServer
        Case Else
            provider = ProviderType.OleDb
    End Select
End If
```

I don't know how or why you got to the `machine.config`, but that shouldn't happen. With your current approach, try specifying the application root when getting the configuration file:

```
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/")
```